# Poner espacios en xslt traidos de sql

Tags: html, xslt

Estoy representando en un xslt unos datos traídos de una consulta sql.

Mi problema es que uno de los campos recuperados del sql tiene varios espacios antes del texto y en el xslt (como pasa en el html) no me pone esos espacios y los necesito.

Esto es lo que me devuelve el sql:
[image: Resultado SQL]

Para representarlo en el xslt lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../../ARBOLVISION/DATOS/REGISTRO">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@TREEVISION"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
```

Si lo hago así no me respeta los espacios que hay en el campo Treevision (El valor * T58920093 * me lo pinta sin los 5 espacios que tiene delante).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si devuelvo desde el sql haciendo un replace del espacio por `&nbsp;` (espacios en HTML) o por  `&#160;` (espacio en XSLT) tampoco me funciona.
Al hacer esto el resultado de la consulta es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en el campo TreeVisionHTML me ha sustituido bien los valores pero al ejecutar el xslt me sale lo siguiente (trabajo con otro campo para no ir modioficando el mismo siempre):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si sustituyo por `&nbsp;` me hace lo mismo, no me pinta el espacio, me imprime `&nbsp;`

(Al incluir estos cambios, en el xslt cambio TREEVIOSION por TREEVISIONHTML para mostrar el campo sobre el que he hecho el REPLACE)

También tengo el campo nEspacios por si fuese posible recuperar ese valor e ir concatenando espacios en el xslt pero no se cómo hacerlo, era una última idea "loca".

Comment: Hola @Marcos, gracias por la ayuda lo primero. Si que lo he intentado poner pero mi xslt es mucho más grande y no me permite ponerlo porque siempre está dentro de otra etiqueta <xsl template...> tampooc lo puedo poner arriba del todo del documento porque puedo fastidiar otras cosas que se muestran con anterioridad...

Comment: Creo que he probado pero pruebo otra vez y te digo.

Comment: Tampoco me funciona @Marcos. He probado a ponerlo en el `<xsl:value-of select="@TREEVISION" xml:space="preserve"/>` , en el `<xsl:for-each select="../../ARBOLVISION/DATOS/REGISTRO">` y en la primera etiqueta del documento y en los dos primeros casos no me hace nada y al ponerla en la primera me ha dado error (el documento es muy grande, cabía esta posibilidad).

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] y también indicar donde/como/con que lo estas visualizando?

Comment: @Marcos, el ejemplo ya está, he descrito totalmente el problema y he mostrado los datos que tengo como origen, como los pinto y el resultado. Lo pruebo en internet explorer. Lo que he hecho es cambiar los espacios por guiones y muestro los guiones porque no tengo manera de hacer lo que quería en origen...

Answer (score 0):

Creo esta respuesta con **un ejemplo** para demostrar que tu código debería funcionar.

- Creamos un archivo llamado **registros.xml** donde vamos a tener:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="registros.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<records>
  <rec id="1">
    <origenid>108801</origenid>
    <destinoid>1088013</destinoid>
    <traza>L03</traza>
    <treevision>X589</treevision>
    <nespacios>5</nespacios>
  </rec>
  <rec id="2">
    <origenid>108802</origenid>
    <destinoid>1088014</destinoid>
    <traza>L02</traza>
    <treevision>X540</treevision>
    <nespacios>5</nespacios>
  </rec>
  <rec id="3">
    <origenid>108804</origenid>
    <destinoid>1088015</destinoid>
    <traza>L01</traza>
    <treevision>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;*T5892*</treevision>
    <nespacios>10</nespacios>
  </rec>
</records>
```

- Creamos un archivo llamado **registros.xsl** donde vamos a definir:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Registros:</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#cd8932">
            <th>TreeVision</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="records/rec">
            <tr bgcolor="#84cd32">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="treevision" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- Ambos archivos deben estar en el mismo nivel/directorio
- Procedemos a abrir el archivo `XML` usando un navegador e ingresando `http://localhost/registros.xml` para obtener el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te invito a crear un [ejemplo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) donde podamos ver que NO funciona.

PD: Esta "respuesta" que no es una respuesta, la voy a borrar cuando la comunidad considere que ya no es necesaria.

Comment: Marcos, he dejado los archivos en github pages: https://jachguate.github.io/SOExercises/586680/registros.xml

Comment: Gracias @jachguate, la verdad que no se me ocurrio usar Github Pages; muy buena idea!

Comment: A mi se me ocurrió ayer y creo que está resultando muy bien para este tipo de casos, que no pueden colocarse directamente en un snippet, pero que son serverless por naturaleza. Un saludo!

Comment: Lo reviso y te digo. Si caducase la recompensa la pondría otra vez y te la daría si me funciona, gracias.

Comment: Sin probarlo todavía te puedo decir que si pongo los "comodines" para poner los espacios a saco en el xml si que los pone bien pero si los traigo del sql no. De todas maneras aun no lo he podido probar, como te he dicho antes, en que lo pruebe digo algo.

Comment: Hola @PabloSimonDiEstefano, entonces te diría que el problema esta en como estas creando el archivo `xml`. Es probable estes codificando o escapando el valor dentro del tag `<treevision>`; ¿Quizas estes usando un `<[CDATA[` ?